# how to define a rank of values for an argument inside a function?

Tags: r, function, arguments

Let's suppose the next function:

```
demo_function <- function(x){

  if(is.na(x)){

    return(NA)

  } else if(1 < x < 2){
    
    return("something")
    
  } else {
    return("Nothing")
  }
}
```

The idea is that when the argument `x` is between 1 and 2, say `x=0.001`, then the function returns something.

However when trying to run the above function, the next error arises:

> Error: no function to go from, jumping to a higher level

How could I adjust the function in order to get `"something"` for the specified argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the `else if` i.e. the syntax in `R` is different than the mathematical notation - multiple expressions are connected by logical operators

```
else if(1 < x  && x < 2)
```

i.e.

```
demo_function <- function(x){
 
   if(is.na(x)){
 
     return(NA)
 
   } else if(1 < x && x < 2){
     return("something")
   } else {
     return("Nothing")
   }
 
 }
> demo_function(0.01)
[1] "Nothing"
> demo_function(1.5)
[1] "something"
> demo_function(NA)
[1] NA
```